# My google map api v3 project crashes after xml load try

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Hi i'am new at google map api and javascript i get some in google chrome js console says 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier ' can someonehelp about it.
downloadxml.js is from geocodezip.com/scripts/downloadxml.js
and example of my xml file is;

```
<marker lat="37.887793" long="32.500402" name="Necmeddin Erbakan Üniversitesi Rektörlüğü" cat="Üniversite" desc="<a href="http://www.konya.edu.tr"target="_blank">Necmeddin Erbakan Üniversitesi</a><br><img src="resimler/konyau.jpg" width="150" height="100" >" ico_wsize="20" ico_hsize="20" ico_wssize="20" ico_hssize="20" ico_icon="icons/university.png"/>
```

Html;

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>   
   <title>KONYA</title>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="downloadxml.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

var map = null;
function createMarker(point, names, html) {
    var contentString = html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: point,
        map: map,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
        }


    function yukle() 
    {
    var mapOptions = 
     { 
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(37.95, 32.505),
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     };
var map= new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.close();
        });



downloadUrl("konya1.xml", function(doc) {
        var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);
        var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          // obtain the attribues of each marker
          var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")) ;
          var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")) ;    
          var point[i] = google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
          var names[i] = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var cat[i] = markers[i].getAttribute("cat");
          var desc[i] = markers[i].getAttribute("desc");
          var ico_wsize = markers[i].getAttribute("ico_wsize");
          var ico_hsize = markers[i].getAttribute("ico_hsize");
          var ico_wssize = markers[i].getAttribute("wssize");
          var ico_hssize = markers[i].getAttribute("hssize");
          var ico_icon = markers[i].getAttribute("ico_icon");
          var marker = createMarker(point[i],names[i],cat[i]);


        }
});
}
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
  { 
    size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', yukle);
//ico_wsize="20" ico_hsize="20" ico_wssize="20" ico_hssize="20" ico_icon="icons/supermarket.png"/>

</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the error:

```
      var point[i] = google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
      var names[i] = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var cat[i] = markers[i].getAttribute("cat");
      var desc[i] = markers[i].getAttribute("desc");
```

You are assigning something directly to array item. You have to do, for example:

```
var point = google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
```

and than push that value to some array (if you have to collect those points, names...)